# Can we restrict in cassandra that a table only have limited number of records or rows?

Tags: cassandra

Can we restrict in cassandra that a table only have limited number of records or rows? If we want to insert maximum 20 rows in a table then how do we do?

Comment: SO is for asking specific questions. Show us what you did and how it went wrong. For documentation you would have to refer to the vendor's web site. You can always learn more about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the Help Center

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra does not support this kind of operation. This is part of the business logic in your application and it should be done on application level.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can make a `PER PARTITION LIMIT` on the query, then issue a delete periodically to create a range tombstone for everything past that range. ie in a

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  primary text
  clustering timestamp
  value text
  PRIMARY KEY ((primary), clustering)
```

You can `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE primary = 'mykey' PER PARTITION LIMIT 20` which then the last one has a clustering of `1548857236000` can then `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE primary = 'mykey' and clustering > 1548857236000`. For most part id just issue that delete very infrequently (like once an hour or a day depending on load in order to keep partition size down) and use LeveledCompactionStrategy. If enough load include a date component to the primary key like `((primary, yyyyMMdd), clustering)` to prevent too much tombstone much buildup in the partition.